# Safari developer on desktop Mac refuse to display the console output when debugging in mobile Safari on iPhone

Tags: safari, console

The console in Safari Developer on my Mac refuses to display any of my console.log messages.

It displays network errors ok.

I've connected my iPhone to my Mac, have the Developer menu displayed in Safari, selected my iPhone from the Developer menu and can see my cookies, storage etc fine, and have 'All' selected at the top of the console. If I type  alert('test'); in the console the alert appears on my phone so it's definitely connected ok.

Is there anything else I should be checking?

I'm getting around it by have all my console.log message display as alerts but that doesn't let me see console.log messages from third party js like my push service worker.

I've also tried debugging on my Windows machine (via the guide here: https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows) which I'm successfully able to do - however console still only displays the network errors - not my console.log() calls.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've upgraded your iPhone to 16.4 and can't no longer have the console.log showing up on your mac while using developer tools to monitor your iPhone on safari, that might be the solution I explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862081/console-log-not-displaying-on-ipad-pro-safari-16-4-when-using-dev-tools-on-my-ma/76005637#76005637)

Comment: Thank you, Giviz. My Mac's a little too old to upgrade to that version of Safari - time for an upgrade